# $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)>0$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove $\exists \epsilon >0: f(x) > \epsilon$ for all $x \in [-10,10]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is my proof below valid as a solution to the problem?

Problem:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that $f(x) > \epsilon$ for all $x \in [-10,10]$.

Attempt:

By the Heine-Borel Theorem, we have that $f$ attains $\min f > 0$ in the closed interval $[-10,10]$ at some point $y \in \mathbb{R}$. We have that
\begin{align*}
f(y) &> 0 \\
\frac{f(y)}{2} &> 0
\end{align*}
Notice that $f(y)>\frac{f(y)}{2}>0$. Let $\epsilon := \frac{f(y)}{2}$ so $f(y)>\epsilon>0$. Hence, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) > \epsilon$ for all $x \in [-10,10]$.

Comment: It looks right to me. But you are actually using Extreme Value Theorem, not Heine-Borel (Heine-Borel is used to prove Extreme Value Theorem).

Comment: yes, it's correct.